# positional arguments are being asked for even though I have included them in my args instead?

Tags: python

Hi I'm writing a program that is meant to do the RK4 method for different ODEs for an assignment. One of the things we have to use is *args. When I call on my function that includes *args(the rk4 one) I list the extra parameters at the end. When I try to run it it says that my function(f2a in this case) is missing 3 required positional arguments even though I have included them at the end in what I assumed was the args section of my RK4 function parameter list. Does this mean I'm not indicating that those are extra parameters correctly? Or do I need to add them to the function I'm using RK4 on? I'm really new to coding so any help is much appreciated. Here is my entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#defining functions
H0=7 #initial height, meters
def f2a(t,H,k,Vin,D):
    dhdt=4/(math.pi*D**2)*(Vin-k*np.sqrt(H))
    return(dhdt)

def fb2(J,t):
    x=J[0]
    y=J[1]
    dxdt=0.25*y-x
    dydt=3*x-y
    #X0,Y0=1,1 initial conditions
    return([dxdt,dydt])



#x0 and y0 are initial conditions
def odeRK4(function,tspan,R,h,*args):
 
    #R is vector of inital conditions
    x0=R[0]
    y0=R[1]


    #writing statement for what to do if h isnt given/other thing
    if h==None:
        h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0])
    elif h> tspan[1]-tspan[0]:
        h=.01*(tspan[1]-tspan[0])
    else:
        h=h
    #defining the 2-element array (i hope)
    #pretty sure tspan is range of t values
    x0=tspan[0] #probably 0 if this is meant for time
    xn=tspan[1] #whatever time we want it to end at?
    #xn is final x value-t
    #x0 is initial

    t_values=np.arange(x0,21,1) #0-20 
    N=len(t_values)
    y_val=np.zeros(N)
    y_val[0]=y0
    #I am trying to print all the Y values into this array
    for i in range(1,N):
        #rk4 method
        #k1
        t1=t_values[i-1] #started range @ 1, n-1 starts at 0
        y1=y_val[i-1]
        k1=function(t1,y1)
    
        #k2
        t2=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
        y2=y_val[i-1]+0.5*k1*h
        k2=function(t2,y2)
    
      
        #k3
        t3=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
        y3=y_val[i-1]+0.5*k2*h
        k3=function(t3,y3)
    
        #k4
        t4=t_values[i-1]+h
        y4=y_val[i-1]+h*k3
        k4=function(t4,y4)
    
        y_val[i]=y_val[i-1]+(1/6)*h*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
        #this fills the t_val array and keeps the loop going

    a=np.column_stack(t_values,y_val)
    print('At time T, Y= (t on left,Y on right)')
    print(a)
    plt.plot(t_values,y_val)


print('For 3A:')
#k=10, told by professor bc not included in instructions
odeRK4(f2a, [0,20],[0,7], None, 10,150,7)
```

Comment: Yes, you need to pass `*args` from RK4 to the function you're integrating itself. Otherwise how would it work? Right now you're only passing two arguments to the `function` that gets passed to RK4.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly pass in the extra arguments that will be stored in the `args` parameter of the function  `odeRK4`, when running this:

```py
# at the end of you snippet ^^
odeRK4(f2a, [0,20],[0,7], None, 10,150,7)
```

However, as you mention `f2a` requires 3 arguments. Looking at the definition of `odeRK4` we see that after passing `f2a` it is now called `function` inside `odeRK4`:

```py
def odeRK4(function,tspan,R,h,*args):
```

In the function `odeRK4` you use `function` like this, and there is no use of `args` to be seen anywhere but the parameters of `odeRK4`:

```py
t1=t_values[i-1] #started range @ 1, n-1 starts at 0
y1=y_val[i-1]
k1=function(t1,y1) # <--- 2 instead of 3 for f2a
    
#k2
t2=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
y2=y_val[i-1]+0.5*k1*h
k2=function(t2,y2)  # <--- 2 instead of 3 for f2a

# more uses...
```

So as you see that are two parameters. In order to pass `args` to the `function`. You must call them like this:

```py
t1=t_values[i-1] #started range @ 1, n-1 starts at 0
y1=y_val[i-1]
k1=function(*args) # <--- fixed
    
#k2
t2=t_values[i-1]+0.5*h
y2=y_val[i-1]+0.5*k1*h
k2=function(*args)  # <--- fixed

# more uses...
```

This resolves you issue with `3 arguments wanted` but this makes your calcution not use your `t1`, `t2` etc. But you have the fix that yourself and use `args` so that it fits your needs.

[Extra] The `*` in front of `args`, in when it is sometimes uses. Like this `*args` is the unpack operator. You can find more here: https://www.scaler.com/topics/python/packing-and-unpacking-in-python/ It is the `...` operator that may be known from js.

Good Luck!